# What are disadvantage of Stub Area in OSPF?

Tags: ospf, stub

Stub areas have many advantages, but can someone tell me what are their disadvantages?

Comment: Can you tell us the "many advantages" first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, a stub area is a dead-end area. For instance, a stub are cannot be used as a transit for virtual links.

[*RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2, Section 3.6 Supporting stub areas*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2328.txt)

> There are a couple of restrictions on the use of stub areas. Virtual
>   links cannot be configured through stub areas.  In addition, AS
>   boundary routers cannot be placed internal to stub areas.

Cisco has a document, [*OSPF Design Guide*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/7039-1.html#t31), that has a section on stub areas:

> An area could be qualified a stub when there is a single exit point
>   from that area or if routing to outside of the area does not have to
>   take an optimal path. The latter description is just an indication
>   that a stub area that has multiple exit points, will have one or more
>   area border routers injecting a default into that area. Routing to the
>   outside world could take a sub-optimal path in reaching the
>   destination by going out of the area via an exit point which is
>   farther to the destination than other exit points.
>
> Other stub area restrictions are that a stub area cannot be used as a
>   transit area for virtual links. Also, an ASBR cannot be internal to a
>   stub area. These restrictions are made because a stub area is mainly
>   configured not to carry external routes and any of the above
>   situations cause external links to be injected in that area. The
>   backbone, of course, cannot be configured as stub.
>
> All OSPF routers inside a stub area have to be configured as stub
>   routers. This is because whenever an area is configured as stub, all
>   interfaces that belong to that area will start exchanging Hello
>   packets with a flag that indicates that the interface is stub.
>   Actually this is just a bit in the Hello packet (E bit) that gets set
>   to 0. All routers that have a common segment have to agree on that
>   flag. If they don't, then they will not become neighbors and routing
>   will not take effect.